# c program for a simple ATM machine using if and else if

Tags: c, visual-c++

I am not able to figure out where is the mistake. When I am trying to run the program, Its not going pass the choice and its going directly to the end of the program after asking for the choice. And, its also giving some warning in "Show output from build" in visual c++ compiler. Can anyone help me with this, please?

```
     #include <stdio.h>
     int main ()
     {
     int card_number, choice, withdraw, deposit;
     float amount = 3000.00, new_amount = 0;
     char password;
     printf("Enter the card number: ");
     scanf("%d", &card_number);
     printf("Enter the Password: ");
     scanf(" %c", &password);
     printf("\n\n");
     printf("\n\t***********************************");
     printf("\n\t*           MENU                  *");
     printf("\n\t*     1. Check Balance            *");
     printf("\n\t*     2. Withdraw                 *");
     printf("\n\t*     3. Deposit                  *");
     printf("\n\t*     4. Exit                     *");
     printf("\n\t*                                 *");
     printf("\n\t***********************************");
     printf("\n\n");
     printf("Enter your choice: ");
     scanf("%d", &choice);

     if (choice == 1)
       {
      printf("Current balance on your account: %f\n", amount);
       }
     else if (choice == 2)
      {
    printf("Enter the amount you want to withdraw: ");
    scanf("%d", &withdraw);

    if (withdraw > amount)
      {
        printf("You don't have sufficient balance");
      }
    else
      {
        new_amount = amount - withdraw;
        printf("Current balance on your account: %f\n", new_amount);
      }
}

else if (choice == 3)
{
    printf("Enter the amount you want to deposit: ");
    scanf("%d", &deposit);
    amount = amount + deposit;
    printf("Current balance on your account: %d\n", amount);
}
else if (choice == 4)
{
    printf("Thank you for using our service\n\n");
}

return 0;
    }
```

Comment: i tried your code, and its seem fine to me. try to debug it(f10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before reading character type this `fflush(stdin);`

or do

```
 scanf(" %c", &password);// see the extra space between '"' and '%'
```

Comment: That is Undefined Behaviour. `fflush` is only for output stream.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked!! However, I am a student of computer science. fflush is new to me. Can you let me know what does it do and also why its giving warning in Visual C++ to use scanf_s instead of scanf.

Comment: @anansharm go here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fflush.htm

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you want the password to be more than one character long, so you need a "string" not a single `char`. Unfortunately, C does not have a string type, but it does have arrays of `char` which is good enough. Instead of requesting a character via `scanf("%c",&password);`, you should request a "string" via `scanf("%s",&password);`. **However**, `password` **must** be defined as an array of `char` long enough to hold the password.[1]

The reason this is causing your program to "skip to the end" is because the `%c` only reads one character of input. You probably typed several characters. Later in the program you attempted to read an `int` via `%d` which could not consume the non-digits of your password and therefore the `scanf()` calls failed, but you did not check the return value from these calls so your code did not know about the failures.

---

[1] Actually `password` must be long enough to hold whatever the user decides to enter. Really you should investigate the use of format widths such as `%20s` to prevent array overruns, which are a serious security hole. But since this is a homework assignment, we'll assume those sorts of details are not really important at the moment.

Comment: **Useful information!** So sad, I can't vote, as I require 15 reputation to do so. However, if I am gonna use "string" as password, instead of doing 'scanf("%s", password)', can i go for 'gets(password)'. what do you suggest will be a better choice from the real world perspective?

Comment: `gets(password)` will have all the same issues `scanf` has. In general the C "string" library is broken from a security point of view. If you really want to try and do it "right", use `fgets()`, it has a length parameter to prevent buffer overruns.

Answer (score 1):

The following code should solve your problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main ()
{
  int card_number, choice;
  float amount = 3000.00, withdraw=0.0, deposit, new_amount=0;
  char password;
  clrscr();
  printf(" INSERT YOUR ATM CARD : ");
  printf("\n\n");
  printf(" Enter the Password: ");
  scanf("%s", &password);
  clrscr();
  printf("\n\t***********************************");
  printf("\n\t*           MENU                  *");
  printf("\n\t*     1. Check Balance            *");
  printf("\n\t*     2. Withdraw                 *");
  printf("\n\t*     3. Deposit                  *");
  printf("\n\t*     4. Exit                     *");
  printf("\n\t*                                 *");
  printf("\n\t***********************************");
  printf("\n\n");
S:
  printf("\n Enter your choice: ");
  scanf("%d", &choice);
  if (choice == 1)
  {
    printf(" Current balance on your account: %f\n", amount);
    goto S;
  }
  else if (choice == 2)
  {
    printf(" Enter the amount you want to withdraw: ");
    scanf("%f",&withdraw);
    if (withdraw>amount)
    {
      printf(" \n You don't have sufficient balance\n ");
      goto S;
    }
    else
    {
      amount = amount - withdraw;
      printf(" \n Current balance on your account: %f\n",amount);
      goto S;
    }
  }
  else if (choice == 3)
  {
    printf(" \n Enter the amount you want to deposit: ");
    scanf("%f", &deposit);
    amount = amount + deposit;
    printf(" \n Current balance on your account: %f\n", amount);
    goto S;
  }
  else if (choice == 4)
  {
    printf(" \n Thank you for using our service\n\n");
    getch();
  }
  else
  {
    printf(" \n Enter correct Choice and Try Again \n\n");
    goto S;
  }

  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream.h>


int main()

{

       int password;

   for (int i=0;i<3;i++)

   {cout <<"enter password:\n";
        cin>>password;

        if (password==123456)
        {cout<<"correct!!!\n";

        double balance = 10000;
        double withdraw, deposit;
        int option;
cout<<"\n";
cout<<"            ***Western Ace***\n";
        cout<<"*** Automated Teller Machine***"<<endl;
        cout<<"Choose a Transaction:\n";
        cout<<"\n";
        cout    <<"[1] Inquire Balance \n"
                <<"[2] Withdraw \n"
                <<"[3] Deposit \n"
                <<"[4] Quit \n"
                <<"\n"
                <<"Enter Option:";
        cin>>option;

    switch(option)
    {
    case 1:
            cout<<"\n[[[BALANCE INQUIRY]]]\n";
            cout.setf(ios::fixed);
            cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
            cout.precision(2);
            cout<<"\n Your current balance is $"<<balance<<endl;
            break;
    case 2:
            cout<<"\n[[[WITHDRAW]]]\n";
            cout<<"Enter amount: $";
            cin>>withdraw;

            balance = balance - withdraw;

            cout.setf(ios::fixed);
            cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
            cout.precision(2);

            cout<<"You withdrew $"<<withdraw<<endl;
            cout<<"Your remaining balance is $"<<balance<<endl;
    continue;
    case 3:
            cout<<"\n[[[DEPOSIT]]]\n";
            cout<<"Enter amount: $";
            cin>>deposit;

            balance = balance + deposit;

            cout.setf(ios::fixed);
            cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
            cout.precision(2);

            cout<<"You deposited $"<<deposit<<endl;
            cout<<"Your new balance is $"<<balance<<endl;
            continue;
            case 4:
            cout<<"\n***[[[EXIT MODE]]]***\n";

    break;


    default:
            cout<<"\n That is an invalid option \n";
    }






            break;
    }
    else


            cout<<"Pls try again!!!\n";}

return 0;
}//
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to add an explanation of how your code works and how it solves the OP's problem. Many SO posters are newbies and will not understand the code you have posted.